# Get project directory name in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the absolute path of a folder I am running the application from. So if the url is `http://localhost/projdir/` then I would like to get this whole path in Jquery.

ANy help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript `window` object to get that:

You can use it like:

```
alert(window.location); //alerts http://localhost/projdir/
```

You can read more about the [window object here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.pathname;`. This will provide the path that are after the localhost

http://localhost/projdir/

```
console.log(window.location.pathname); //will give projdir/ as output
```